# C#: Expensiveness in checking the type of a variable

Tags: c#

How expensive is it to check the type of a variable in C#?

E.g. using `try`/`catch` vs. using `as` vs. using `typeof`.

Absolute measurements are not necessary. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`try` / `catch` is definitely slower, since a thrown exception causes stack information to be gathered.

`as`/`is` are for comparing to a type known at compile time and cater for inheritance (ie. `"string" is Object` returns `true`)

`typeof`/`GetType()` can be used for types known at runtime but do not cater for inheritance (ie. `"string".GetType() == typeof(Object)` returns `false`)

Regardless, I think you probably want `as` (or `is` if you don't need the cast value)

Answer (score 3):

Which is *expensive* is completely irrelevant; you should *never use exception handling as a form of control flow if you can avoid it*. It's called "exception handling" because it should only happen in *exceptional, unavoidable circumstances*.  Invalid type conversion exceptions are *bugs* and should be fixed. *Always* use "is", "as", or "GetType()" to determine the type of a thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check that type, you should go with `is` operator.